# Is it right to use a "for" loop to create a loop that check input value?

Tags: c, loops

I need to write a program that requests two floating-point numbers and prints the value of
their difference divided by their product, and to have the program loop through pairs of
input values until the user enters nonnumeric input. I need to use `scanf` to take the input.

So, as I know that scanf return a value 0 or 1 for true/false so I though testing it to accomplish the last part of the question, but I'm trying to figure out how to make sure the loop goes back to ask for input.

My code is:

```
int main()    
{        
    double num1, num2, different, product, answer;

    printf("please enter 2 floatig point numbers:\n");
    printf("number one is?\n");
    while (scanf("%lf", &num1) ==1)
    {
        printf("number two is?\n");
        while (scanf("%lf", &num2) ==1)
        {       
            if (num1 > num2)
            {
                different = num1 - num2;
            }

            if (num2 > num1)        
            {
                different = num2 - num1;
            }

            if (num1 == num2)        
            {
                different = 0;
            }

            product = num1*num2;
            answer = different/product;
            printf("%lf", answer);
        }
        printf("you're out!");
    }
    printf("you're out!");
}
```

Example input:

```
first num 4.5
second num 3.5
```

output:

```
please enter 2 floatig point numbers:
number one is?
4.5
number two is?
3.5
0.063492
```

I'm getting the right answer and the program keeps running but I'm looking for a solution to go back for the input request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first note that whatever made your `scanf` fail the first time, will probably make it fail the second time. So a loop such as this:

```
while (scanf("%lf", &a) != 1);
```

**could become an infinite loop**.

Also, when reading two or more values at the same time, it would be hard to track what is read and what is not. Therefore, I advise reading the values one by one, in a form like this:

```
void clear_line()
{
    char c;
    while (scanf("%c", &c) == 1)
        if (c == '\n')
            return;
}

double read_value(const char *message)
{
    double d;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("%s", message);
        if (scanf("%lf", &d) == 1)
            return d;
        if (feof(stdin))
        {
            printf("Unexpected end of file\n");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("Invalid input\n");
        clear_line();
    }
}

...
num1 = read_value("Enter first number: ");
num2 = read_value("Enter second number: ");
if (feof(stdin))
    /* handle error */
```

What this basically does is try reading the value until the user produces a correct one. In case of incorrect input, one line of input is consumed and thrown away so the left over of whatever the user has input would not affect the next `scanf` and create a chain of errors.

Comment: thanks allot! i didnt get to pointer yet, and this exercise is not using functions, but its good to know it :)

Answer (score 1):

Its just simply a pattern to define the number of input are you wanting. the simpler version of your code is

```
  while( scanf("%d %d", &a,&b) == 2 )
  //
```

here `scanf` return the 2 as a return value.

so you are checking `while(2 == 2)`, make the number of input are you wanting

```
while( scanf("%lf %lf", &num1,&numb2) == 2 )
{
    if (num1 > num2)
    {
        different = num1 - num2;
    }

    if (num2 > num1)
    {
        different = num2 - num1;
    }

    if (num1 == num2)
    {
        different = 0;
    }
    product = num1*num2;
}
```

Comment: thanks man! really helpful. But this code is not going to add the text before asking the number from the user (printf("number one is?\n")) right? its only going to let you add more numbers @Nikson Kanti Paul

Comment: you can tell user to input two number at a time :P, no you can't say one by one in this style. i think you got the point what is your question ?

Comment: Yes got it thanks. It's just that I want to add the text that asks him to write two new numbers each time..@Nikson Kanti Paul

Comment: my solution: while( printf("please enter 2 floatig point numbers:\n")&& scanf("%lf %lf", &num1,&num2) == 2 ) worked...but im not sure about the style..:/ @Nikson Kanti Paul

Comment: `printf` return the length of the string as return value. so your printf condition part is greater then 0, `while( 41 && 2==2)` that is your condition now. you can check simply `int len = printf(....)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like:

```
while(1)
{
     printf("number one is?\n");
     if(scanf("%lf", &num1) != 1)
     {
       break;
     }
     printf("number teo is?\n");
     if(scanf("%lf", &num2) != 1)
     {
       break;
     }

    if (num1 > num2)
    {
        different = num1 - num2;
    }

    if (num2 > num1)

    {
        different = num2 - num1;
    }

    if (num1 == num2)

    {
        different = 0;
    }

    product = num1*num2;

    answer = different/product;

    printf("%lf", answer);

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `scanf(...) < 1` then break. The code also doesn't make sense as there are 2 `scanf` for `num2`

Comment: No, but it still doesn't make sense by trying to read double into num2 twice.